# Installing Erlang on Ubuntu Fails

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, ubuntu-14.04

Using instructions [here](https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/) (Erlang Solutions); I get this error:

```
Fetched 39.9 MB in 10min 54s (61.0 kB/s)                                       
(Reading database ... 409261 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../esl-erlang_1%3a18.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking esl-erlang (1:18.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/esl-erlang_1%3a18.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/erlang/lib/jinterface-1.6.1/ebin/jinterface.app', which is also in package erlang-jinterface 1:18.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/esl-erlang_1%3a18.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And installation fails. Also why there is a URL encoded dot character (%3a) instead of a dot itself in the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove previously installed Erlang packages (like `erlang-jinterface` mentioned in your error message). Then you will be able to install `esl-erlang`.